# MCTS Agent making bad decisions on Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, monte-carlo-tree-search

I've been working on a MCTS AI for a couple days now. I tried to implement it on Tic-Tac-Toe, the least complex game I could think of, but for some reason, my AI keeps making bad decisions. I've tried change the values of UCB1's exploration constant, the number of iterations per search, and even the points awarded to winning, losing, and getting to tie the game (trying to make a tie more rewarding, as this AI only plays second, and try to get a draw, win otherwise). As of now, the code looks like this:

```
import random
import math
import copy
class tree:
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.board = board
        self.visits = 0
        self.score = 0
        self.children = []
class mcts:
    def search(self, mx, player,):
        root = tree(mx)
        for i in range(1200):
            leaf = mcts.expand(self, root.board, player, root)
            result = mcts.rollout(self, leaf)
            mcts.backpropagate(self, leaf, root, result)
        return mcts.best_child(self, root).board

    def expand(self, mx, player, root):
        plays = mcts.generate_states(self, mx, player) #all possible plays
        if root.visits == 0:
            for j in plays:
                root.children.append(j) #create child_nodes in case they havent been created yet
        for j in root.children:
            if j.visits == 0:
                return j #first iterations of the loop
        for j in plays:
            if mcts.final(self, j.board, player):
                return j
        return mcts.best_child(self, root) #choose the one with most potential

    def rollout(self, leaf):
        mx = leaf.board
        aux = 1
        while mcts.final(self, mx, "O") != True:
            if aux == 1: # "X" playing
                possible_states = []
                possible_nodes = mcts.generate_states(self, mx, "X")
                for i in possible_nodes:
                    possible_states.append(i.board)
                if len(possible_states) == 1: mx =  possible_states[0]
                else:
                    choice = random.randrange(0, len(possible_states) - 1)
                    mx = possible_states[choice]
                if mcts.final(self, mx, "X"): #The play by "X" finished the game
                    break
            elif aux == 0: # "O" playing
                possible_states = []
                possible_nodes = mcts.generate_states(self, mx, "O")
                for i in possible_nodes:
                    possible_states.append(i.board)
                if len(possible_states) == 1: mx =  possible_states[0]
                else:
                    choice = random.randrange(0, len(possible_states) - 1)
                    mx = possible_states[choice]
            aux += 1
            aux = aux%2
        if mcts.final(self, mx, "X"):
            for i in range(len(mx)):
                for k in range(len(mx[i])):
                    if mx[i][k] == "-":
                        return -1 #loss
            return 0 #tie
        elif mcts.final(self, mx, "O"):
            for i in range(len(mx)):
                for k in range(len(mx[i])):
                    if mx[i][k] == "-":
                        return 1 #win


    def backpropagate(self, leaf, root, result): # updating our prospects stats
        leaf.score += result
        leaf.visits += 1
        root.visits += 1

    def generate_states(self, mx, player):
        possible_states = [] #generate child_nodes
        for i in range(len(mx)):
            for k in range(len(mx[i])):
                if mx[i][k] == "-":
                    option = copy.deepcopy(mx)
                    option[i][k] = player
                    child_node = tree(option)
                    possible_states.append(child_node)
        return possible_states

    def final(self,mx, player): #check if game is won
        possible_draw = True
        win = False
        for i in mx: #lines
            if i == [player, player, player]:
                win = True
                possible_draw = False
        if mx[0][0] == player: #diagonals
            if mx[1][1] == player:
                if mx[2][2] == player:
                    win = True
                    possible_draw = False
        if mx[0][2] == player:
            if mx[1][1] == player:
                if mx[2][0] == player:
                    win = True
                    possible_draw = False
        for i in range(3): #columns
            if mx[0][i] == player and mx[1][i] == player and mx[2][i] == player:
                win = True
                possible_draw = False
        for i in range(3):
            for k in range(3):
                if mx[i][k] == "-":
                    possible_draw = False
        if possible_draw:
            return possible_draw
        return win

    def calculate_score(self, score, child_visits, parent_visits, c): #UCB1
        return score / child_visits + c * math.sqrt(math.log(parent_visits) / child_visits)

    def best_child(self, root): #returns most promising node
        treshold = -1*10**6
        for j in root.children:
            potential = mcts.calculate_score(self, j.score, j.visits, root.visits, 2)
            if potential > treshold:
                win_choice = j
                treshold = potential
        return win_choice

#todo the AI takes too long for each play, optimize that by finding the optimal approach in the rollout phase
```

First off, the purpose of this AI is to return an altered matrix, with the best play he could make in that circunstance. I find myself questioning if the MCTS algorithm is the reason behind all these broken plays, due to some possible mistakes in its implementation. With that said, in my eyes, the code does the following:

1. Check if the root already has its children, in case it has, choose the most promising.
2. Rollout a random simulation and save the result.
3. Update the leaf's score, its number of visits and the root's number of visits.
4. Repeat for 1200 iterations, in my example
5. Return the best move (matrix, child_node) possible.

Why is it not working? Why is it choosing bad plays instead of the optimal one? Is the algorithm wrongly implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was choosing the node with the most visits in the expansion phase, when it should have been the one with the most potential according to the UCB1 formula. I also had some errors when it came to implementing some if clauses, as  all the losses weren't being counted.

Comment: Kindly suggest you [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your own answer, so that the question looks indeed answered.